# vuex: state field "foo" was overridden by a module with the same name at "foo"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting this warning in the console:

```
[vuex] state field "foo" was overridden by a module with the same name at "foo"
```

What does it mean and what can I have done wrong?

Comment: Do you have any `modules` defined in your store?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a new warning added in Vuex 3.1.2.

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/releases/tag/v3.1.2

It is logged when a property name within the `state` conflicts with the name of a module, like so:

```js
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  modules: {
    foo: {}
  }
})
```

If you attempt to access `state.foo` you might expect the value to be `'bar'` but it will actually refer to the `state` of the `foo` module.

You would fix this problem by removing the property from the `state` object, or by renaming either the property or the module.

Here's a small example that logs the relevant warning and shows the resulting value of `state.foo`:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  modules: {
    foo: { state: { flag: 2 } }
  }
})

console.log(store.state.foo)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.4.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
```

**Update:**

This warning can also be logged if you create multiple stores using the same configuration object, e.g. during testing.

Here's an example:

```js
const config = {
  state: {},

  modules: {
    foo: {}
  }
}

const store1 = new Vuex.Store(config)
const store2 = new Vuex.Store(config)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.4.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the configuration includes a root `state` object. The first store adds the `foo` module to that object. When the second store tries to do the same thing it finds that the property already exists and logs the error.

If the root `state` object is empty, like it is in my example, then it could just be removed. However, assuming it isn't empty you'd fix this by changing it to a function instead:

```js
const config = {
  state () {
    return {
      /* state properties here */
    }
  },

  modules: {
    foo: {}
  }
}
```

This works exactly the same way as the `data` function for a component.

Comment: "This is a new warning added in Vuex 3.1.2.". Ok, this is why it came out of the blue...Thanks!!

Comment: I still have a problem with TypeScript though. If I remove foo from state I get:
"Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'State'". That is why I added it to the root state to begin with. How do I tell TypeScript that store.state.foo really means the state of module foo?

Comment: @mspoulsen I don't use TypeScript myself. A quick search threw up https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8, which may help.

Comment: Solution to typescript problem: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1652